# Calculate object A, then return object B that references A in Rust

Tags: rust

In my code I often want to calculate a new value `A`, and then return some view of that value `B`, because `B` is a type that's more convenient to work with. The simplest case is where `A` is a vector and `B` is a slice that I would like to return. Let's say I want to write a function that returns a set of indices. Ideally this would return a slice directly because then I can use it immediately to index a string.

If I return a vector instead of a slice, I have to use `to_slice`:

```rust
fn all_except(except: usize,  max:usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    (0..except).chain((except + 1)..max).collect()
}
"abcdefg"[all_except(1, 7)]
```

```
string indices are ranges of `usize`
the type `str` cannot be indexed by `Vec<usize>`
help: the trait `SliceIndex<str>` is not implemented for `Vec<usize>`
```

I can't return a slice directly:

```rust
fn all_except(except: usize,  max:usize) -> &[usize] {
    (0..except).chain((except + 1)..max).collect()
}
"abcdefg"[all_except(1, 7)]
```

```
                                            ^ expected named lifetime parameter
missing lifetime specifier
help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value with an elided lifetime, but the lifetime cannot be derived from the arguments
help: consider using the `'static` lifetime
```

I can't even return the underlying vector *and* a slice of it, for the same reason

```rust
pub fn except(index: usize, max: usize) -> (&[usize], Vec<usize>) {
    let v = (0..index).chain((index + 1)..max).collect();
    (v, v.as_slice)
}
"abcdefg"[all_except(1, 7)[1]
```

Now it may be possible to hack this particular example using deref coercion (I'm not sure), but I have encountered this problem with more complex types. For example, I have a function that loads an `ndarray::Array2<T>` from CSV file, then want to split it into two parts using `array.split_at()`, but this returns two `ArrayView2<T>` which reference the original `Array2<T>`, so I encounter the same issue. In general I'm wondering if there's a solution to this problem in general. Can I somehow tell the compiler to move `A` into the parent frame's scope, or let me return a tuple of `(A, B)`, where it realises that the slice is still valid because `A` is still alive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't seem to make any sense, you can't index a string using a slice. If you could the first snippet would have worked with just an `as_slice` in the caller or something, vecs trivially coerce to slices. That's exactly what the compiler error is telling you: the compiler is looking for a [`SliceIndex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.SliceIndex.html) and a `Vec` (or slice) is definitely not that.

That aside,

> Can I somehow tell the compiler to move A into the parent frame's scope, or let me return a tuple of (A, B), where it realises that the slice is still valid because A is still alive?

There are packages like `owning_ref` which can bundle owner and reference to avoid extra allocations. It tends to be somewhat fiddly.

I don't think there's any other general solution, because Rust reasons at the function level, the type checker has no notion of "tell the compiler to move A into the parent scope". So you need a construct which works around borrow checker.

Comment: Uhh yes that's true. My real life example was indexing an `ndarray::Array` using `select()`, which *does* take a slice. I was trying to simplify my scenario but obviously that didn't work out. I like the sound of `owning_ref`, however!

Comment: @Migwell I don't know ndarray well but IIRC it has methods to slice arrays in-place for this sort of use-cases, you may want to root around `ArrayBase` for methods which either don't return anything or return an owned array(base).